# pngquant and shell_exec checking status code and then saving image

Tags: php, png, pngquant

I have the following code that seems to be generating a corrupted image. Photoshop says "PNG file corrupted by ASCII conversion"

```
    $path_pngquant = "pngquant";
    $status_code = null;
    $image = null;
    $output = null;

    $image_input_escaped = escapeshellarg('test.png');

    $command = "$path_pngquant --strip -- - < $image_input_escaped";

    // Execute the command
    exec($command, $output, $status_code);

    if($status_code == 0)
    {
        //0 means success
        $image = implode('', $output);
        file_put_contents('test_2.png', $image);
    }
```

Comment: How do you know `$output` is valid image data? You never even use `$image_input_escaped`. Let alone your `$command` seems undefined.

Comment: Sorry that’s a copy paste error. I left out the part that runs the command, the command runs and creates a 40kb png that can’t be opened.

Comment: What's the purpose of the less than sign? Which version of `pngquant` is this?

Comment: I ask because i just did some automatic png compression with *pngquant* with repetitive automatic reductions. But unlike your approach, i had a console php script create a batch (*.bat or *.cmd ...  in Windows) do the deed after successive renaming of resulting output. Not seeing a lesser than sign in help docs. Is this a "linux" switch?

Comment: < and - are for using stdout for saving the output to a variable and not to the file system. < is specifically for reading from given filepath

Comment: Ok. Is that perhaps the source of corruptions since `stdout` is ascii and *not* binary? Further what's your logic by imploding the "output" on sentinel empty string? Empty string is empty right, an not null? Not seeing the point of such implode, if output is raw data and not an array.

Comment: ... Very well. But `stdout` is ascii so corruption happens.

Comment: Imploding the array because exec returns an array of output (each line of output) so imploding with '' makes it one string (image file data) with no spaces. The issue did indeed seem to be that stdout is ascii..

Answer (score 0):

[exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec) will mess up the binary stream what you need is to open the output stream in binary mode read from it. Luckily [popen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) is  just for that

```
    <?php
 $path_pngquant = "pngquant";
    $status_code = null;
    $image = null;
    $output = null;

    $image_input_escaped = escapeshellarg('test.png');

    $command = "$path_pngquant --strip -- - < $image_input_escaped";

    // Execute the command
    $handle = popen($command . '2>&1', 'rb'); //MODE : r =read ; b = binary 

    if($handle){
        $output = '';

        while (!feof($handle)) {
            echo $output;
            $output .= fread($handle, 10240); //10240 = 10kb ; read in chunks of 10kb , change it as per need
        }
        fclose($handle);
     
        file_put_contents('test_2.png', $output);
    }
```

**2>&1** is [redirection syntax](https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect/) used in common shell scripts

Comment: That makes a lot of sense with the binary stream getting messed up. One question though, in my original I check if($status_code == 0) is there any way to read status code with popen?

Comment: Yes in case of errors `$handle` will be set to false